# News item read more button

Tags: php

I'm making a news block for a website. I want if a news message has more than 64 words it shows a read more button. And if it has less then 64 words that just the message is shown. Now I already have the part with the read more button, but i can't get the part that if it has less then 64 words that the read more button dissapears. So the read more button is visible whether it has less or more than 64 words.

This is the piece of code

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM seo_nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row) {
?>
<h4><?php echo $row['titel']; ?></h4> 

<?php
}
?>  
<?php
function limit_words($string, $word_limit){
$words = explode(" ",$string);
return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}
$start = limit_words($row['bericht'],64);                       
?>

<div class="nieuws-tekst"><?php echo $start; ?><?= '...' ?></div>
    <a class="button" href="http://www.linkofwebsite.nl/laatste-nieuws/nieuwsbericht.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Lees meer</a>
```

Update:

```
<?php
function limit_words($string, $word_limit){
$limitReached = FALSE;
$words = explode(" ",$string);
$content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
if (count($words) >= $word_limit) {
$limitReached = TRUE;
}

return array($limitReached, $content);
}
list($limitReached, $content) = limit_words($row['bericht'],64);
?>

<div class="nieuws-tekst">
<?= $content; ?>
<?php if ($limitReached): ?>
... <a class="button" href="http://www.linkofwebsite.nl/laatste-nieuws/nieuwsbericht.php?id=<?= $row['id']; ?>">Lees meer</a>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

This is what I got now after a reaction. But the content shows but the read more button does not.

**Output after var_dump($row['bericht]);**

string(817) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. xercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea "

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt

Comment: count the number of words using str_word_count() function and use the conditional statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as jitendrapurohit already said, you can update your function to count the words.

if `$string` is html you have to make sure your functions handles that properly. otherwise you might end up with invalid html.

for example

```
$string = '<div>some long text</div>';
```

then when you truncate it after 64 words the `div` will not be closed.

here's an updated version of @jitendrapurohit's function which will also remove html from the string.

```
<?php

function limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $limitReached = false;
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    if (count($words) >= $word_limit) {
        $limitReached = true;
    }

    $content = implode(' ', array_splice($words, 0, $word_limit));

    return [$limitReached, $content];
}

list($limitReached, $content) = limit_words($row['bericht'], 64);

?>

<div class="nieuws-tekst">
    <?= $content; ?>
    <?php if ($limitReached): ?>
        <a class="button" href="http://www.linkofwebsite.nl/laatste-nieuws/nieuwsbericht.php?id=<?= $row['id']; ?>">
            Lees meer
        </a>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

update:
array_slice changes its input. so after calling `$content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));` $words contains all words except the first 64. i updated the function.

Comment: Still got the problem that it only shows the read more button on 127 words or more.

Comment: can you post the output of `var_dump($row['bericht]);`?

Comment: If I did it correctly it says NULL. I think that's not that good hahaha
- Wait i did something wrong

Comment: It starts with string(817) then the whole news message between " " and then the message what shows only the 64 words.

Comment: please post the whole message in your question.

Comment: The whole message is in my question.

Comment: @Rolinda Strijker i updated my answer. does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

To make this dynamic, change your function to something like this :

```
function limit_words($string, $word_limit){
    $limitReached = FALSE;
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    $content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
    if (count($words) >= $word_limit) {
        $limitReached = TRUE;
    }

    return array($limitReached, $content);
}
```

Change your calling part to

```
list($limitReached, $content) = limit_words($row['bericht'],64);
```

and then check for it:

```
<div class="nieuws-tekst">
    <?= $content;
  if ($limitReached) { ?>
       <a class="button" href="http://www.linkofwebsite.nl/laatste-nieuws/nieuwsbericht.php?id=<?= $row['id']; ?>">Lees meer</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't use this part anymore then? <div class="nieuws-tekst"><?php echo $start; ?><?= '...' ?></div>

Comment: @RolindaStrijker modify the last two lines as done in the updated answer

Comment: Sorry another question again haha i'm fairly new to PHP. So I have the function and the calling part in between <?php ?> So I guess that I have to make a new <?php ?> for the if statement? But if i do so, the whole website is down.

Comment: @jbe I don't know whats going wrong, because he doesn't show the part between the if ($limitReached). He shows the content but not the read more button.

Comment: read more button will not be seen if the limit of 64 is not reached. are you saying that the button is not shown even if the limit is reached to 64(i.e word count > 64) ?

Comment: I tested it out. When i have like 70 words in my news message the read more button won't show but it has to show then. So I tried out at what count the read more button shows. The read more buttons shows with 127 words or more.

Comment: @RolindaStrijker may be you've made some errors while switching b/w HTML and PHP. Can you please check the updated answer ?

Comment: if `$content` is html you might need to use `strip_tags()` or `htmlspecialchars ()`

Answer (score 0):

just put your button code in an if

```
<?php
    if (limit_words > 64) {
        echo "<a class="button" href="http://www.linkofwebsite.nl/laatste-nieuws/nieuwsbericht.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Lees meer</a>"}
?>
```

Comment: This looked like a nice solution, but to bad it doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to know the word count, in a way or another, and adapt the `(limit_words > 64)` in a way your code can pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $string= 'this is a good choice';
   if(str_word_count($string)>64){
 ?>
 <a href="#"><?php echo substr($string,0,63)?> Read More</a>
 <?php
   }else{
      echo $string;
   }
?>
```

Use [str_word_count ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) function for count words. And use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to show just 64 words.

Comment: `substr($string,0,63)` will return 64 characters. not 64 words.